# How to geo_distance filter against multiple location fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: search, search-engine, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have an arbitrary # of location data points per document (anywhere up to 80).  I want to perform a geo_distance filter against these locations.  The elasticsearch docs claim that:

```
  The geo_distance filter can work with multiple locations / points per document. 
  Once a single location / point matches the filter, the document will be included in the filter.
```

It's never made clear how to achieve this.  I assume that you have to define the # of locations ahead of time, such that your indexed document looks contains these nested fields:

```
 {
"pin" : {
    "location" : {
        "lat" : 40.12,
        "lon" : -71.34
    }
  }
}

{
"alt_pin" : {
    "location" : {
        "lat" : 41.12,
        "lon" : -72.34
    }
}
}
```

I assume that you would then filter against pin.location and alt_pin.location somehow.

What if I had an arbitrary number of locations (pin1, pin2, pin3, ...)?  Can I do something like this:

```
"pin" : {
    "locations" : [{
        "lat" : 41.12,
        "lon" : -72.34
    }, {
        "lat" : 41.12,
        "lon" : -72.34
    }]
}
}
```

Would some variation on that work?  Maybe using geo_hashes instead of lat/lng coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `location` values can be represented as an array of `location` fields. Try this:

```
{
    "pin": [
        {
            "location" :{
                "lat": 40.12,
                "lon": -71.34
            }
        },
        {
            "location" :{
                "lat": 41.12,
                "lon": -72.34
            }
        }
    ]
}
```